# Let $A, B \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $m(A \setminus B)=0$. Show that $\int_A f \le \int _B f$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $A, B \subset \Bbb R^n$ and $m(A \setminus B)=0$. Show that $\int_A f \le \int _B f$.

I currently have the following since $A \cup B = (A \setminus B) \cup(B \setminus A) \cup (A \cap B)$ and $A \subseteq A \cup B$ what I would like to say is that $$\int_A f \le \int_{A \cup B} f = \int_{A \setminus B} f + \int_{B \setminus A} f + \int_{A \cap B} f$$ but since $m(A\setminus B) = 0$ I have $\int_{A \setminus B} f = 0$ so $$\int_A f \le \int_{A \cup B} f = \int_{B \setminus A} f + \int_{A \cap B} f $$ and since $(B \setminus A) \cup (B \cap A) = B$ I have $$\int_A f \le \int_{A \cup B} f = \int_{B} f .$$ Does the integral have an additive property like the Lebesgue measure or is this wrong?

Comment: With  $f \ge 0$?

Answer (score 1):

The integral is indeed additive, but you may want to remark that this follows because $B \setminus A$ and $A \cap B$ are disjoint.